# body.stream().pipe(dest); TypeError: body.stream(...).pipe is not a function

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, gmail-api

We need to run a scheduled job in expressjs server every 10 minutes where the gmail api is used to scan the emails in inbox of one of the gmail account for specific subject. Once the criteria is met the messages and attachment of the email needs to be stored in firebase storage and firebase realtime database.

The code works totally fine in the local environment but when deployed on an ubuntu server the below error is given and the server keeps crashing and the information is also not stored in firebase.

```
/home/ubuntu/project_name/node_modules/@firebase/storage/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:650
        body.stream().pipe(dest);
                      ^

TypeError: body.stream(...).pipe is not a function
    at writeToStream (/home/ubuntu/project_name/node_modules/@firebase/storage/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:650:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/project_name/node_modules/@firebase/storage/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1627:3
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (/home/ubuntu/project_name/node_modules/@firebase/storage/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1407:9)
    at FetchConnection.send (/home/ubuntu/project_name/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.node.cjs.js:558:16)
    at doTheRequest (/home/ubuntu/project_name/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1032:18)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/project_name/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.node.cjs.js:816:13)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)
```

Below is the code for which the error is shown:

```
const schedule = require("node-schedule");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const { authorize } = require("./authenticate");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const UserModel = require("./models/UserModel");
const Buffer = require("buffer").Buffer;
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/storage');

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.BACKEND_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.BACKEND_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.BACKEND_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.BACKEND_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.BACKEND_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.BACKEND_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.BACKEND_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

module.exports = async function () {
    const db = admin.database();
    const storage = firebase.storage();
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    
    console.log('-----latest-----')
    schedule.scheduleJob("*/10 * * * *", async function () {
        db.ref("timings/").once("value", async (snapshotTimings) => {
            const auth = await authorize();
            const timingRefValue = snapshotTimings.val();
            if(!timingRefValue) return ;
            const refIds = Object.keys(timingRefValue);
            await Promise.all(
                refIds.map(async (refId) => {
                    let messageCount = 0;
                    let userMessageCount = {};
                    const gmail = await google.gmail({ version: "v1", auth });
                    const response = await gmail.users.messages.list({
                        userId: "me",
                        q: "subject:Company Name: " + refId,
                    });
                    const messages = response.data.messages;
                    if (!messages?.length || !messages) return null;
                    const threads = {};
                    const repliesArr = [];
                    let repliesCount = 0; 
                    await Promise.all(messages.map( async ({ threadId, id }) => {
                    if(threads[threadId]) return ;
                    threads[threadId] = id;
                    // const threadId = messages[0].threadId;
                    const replies = await gmail.users.threads.get({ userId: "me", id: threadId });
                    repliesArr.push(replies)
                    repliesCount = repliesCount+(replies.data.messages.length || 0);
                    })).then(async ()=> {
                        await Promise.all(repliesArr.map( async (replies) => {
                        const totalReplies = replies.data.messages;
                        // console.log(refId, timingRefValue[refId]?.lastEmailFetchCount,repliesCount)
                        if (timingRefValue[refId]?.lastEmailFetchCount !== repliesCount) {
                            // // console.log('-----3-----')
                            // TODO: Sending the replies to the DB code comes here
                            await Promise.all(totalReplies.map(async ({ id, payload: message }) => {
                                const response1 = await gmail.users.messages.get({
                                    id,
                                    userId: 'me'
                                })
                                let attachments = [];
                                await Promise.all(response1.data.payload.parts.map(async (part,idx)=> {
                                    if (part.body.attachmentId) {
                                        // console.log(id,'---------',refId,'-----',idx,'-------part.body.attachmentId---------',part.body.attachmentId,'\n\n\n\n\n')
                                   
                                      }
                                    if(part.mimeType !== "multipart/alternative" && part.filename && part.body.attachmentId) {
                                        const response2 = await gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
                                            messageId: id,
                                            id: part.body.attachmentId,
                                            userId: 'me'
                                        })
                                        
                                        attachments.push({
                                            mimeType : part.mimeType,
                                            attachmentData : response2.data.data,
                                            attachmentName : part.filename,
                                            attachmentId : part.body.attachmentId
                                        })
                                        
                                  }
                                }))
                                let new_message_text = '';
                                // console.log("msg",message.parts[0])
                                if(message?.parts?.[0]) {
                                    if(message?.parts?.[0]?.mimeType=="text/plain"){
                                        const message_text = await Buffer.from(message.parts[0].body.data, "base64").toString("utf-8");
                                        const lines = message_text.split("\n");
                                        const new_message_lines = await lines.filter((line) =>
                                            line.includes("wrote:") ? false : !line.startsWith(">")
                                        );
                                        new_message_text = await new_message_lines.join("\n").trim();
                                    }else if(message?.parts?.[0]?.mimeType=="multipart/alternative"){
                                        message?.parts?.[0].parts.forEach(item=>{
                                          if(item.mimeType=="text/plain"){
                                            const message_text = Buffer.from(item.body.data, "base64").toString("utf-8");
                                            const lines = message_text.split("\n");
                                            const new_message_lines =  lines.filter((line) =>
                                                line.includes("wrote:") ? false : !line.startsWith(">")
                                            );
                                            new_message_text =  new_message_lines.join("\n").trim();
                                            }
                                        })
                                      }           
                                }
                                const headers = message.headers;
                                const date_header = await headers.find((header) => header.name === "Date");
                                const from_header = await headers.find((header) => header.name === "From");
                                
                                console.log('-----4-----')
                                const time_stamp = date_header ? date_header.value : "";
                                const from = from_header ? from_header.value : "";
                                const re = /[^< ]+(?=>)/g;
                                let extractedEmail = '';
                                if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(from))
                                {
                                    extractedEmail = from;
                                } else {
                                    const emails = from.match(re);
                                    // console.log(refId,emails    )
                                    if(emails.length > 0)
                                    extractedEmail = emails[0]
                                }
                                // // console.log('-----5-----')
                                if(extractedEmail !== process.env.SENDER_EMAIL) {
                                    
                                console.log('-----6-----')
                                    let user = {};
                                    if(extractedEmail)
                                    user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: extractedEmail });
                                    console.log(user,extractedEmail)
                                    console.log('createdon',new Date(time_stamp));
                                    console.log('email',extractedEmail);
                                    console.log('firstName',user?.firstName || '');
                                    console.log('lastName',user?.lastName || '');
                                    console.log('text',new_message_text);
                                    console.log('type',"text");
                                    console.log('userid',user?._id || '');
                                    messageCount++;
                                    if(message?.parts?.[0]?.body?.data) {
                                        await db.ref("messages/" + refId + "/" + new Date(time_stamp).getTime()).set({
                                            createdon: time_stamp,
                                            email: extractedEmail,
                                            firstName: user?.firstName || '',
                                            lastName: user?.lastName || '',
                                            text: new_message_text,
                                            type: "text",
                                            userid: user?._id?.toString() || ''
                                        });
                                    }
                                    console.log("cam here 2 ")
                                    if(attachments.length) {
                                        try{
                                            const uploadPromises = attachments.map(async (attachment,idx) => {
                                                const fileData = attachment.attachmentData;
                                                const buffer = Buffer.from(fileData, 'base64');
                                                const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`attachments/${attachment.attachmentId}`);
                                                const snapshot = await storageRef.put(buffer, { contentType: attachment.mimeType });
                                                const downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                                                let attachmentUrl = downloadUrl
                                                await db.ref("messages/" + refId + "/" + new Date(time_stamp).getTime() + idx).set({
                                                    createdon: time_stamp,
                                                    email: extractedEmail,
                                                    firstName: user?.firstName || '',
                                                    lastName: user?.lastName || '',
                                                    text: null,
                                                    url: attachmentUrl,
                                                    type: "attachment",
                                                    userid: user?._id?.toString() || '',
                                                    attachmentName: attachment.attachmentName,
                                                });
                                                return downloadUrl;
                                            });
                                            await Promise.all(uploadPromises);
                                        }catch(err){
                                            console.log("error",err)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    const msgId = new Date(time_stamp).getTime();
                                    const userMessageKey = refId + '/'+ user?._id?.toString();
                                    if(userMessageCount[userMessageKey]) {
                                        userMessageCount[userMessageKey]++;
                                    } else {
                                        userMessageCount[userMessageKey] = 1;
                                    }
                                    await db.ref('/users/'+ refId + '/'+ user?._id?.toString()).update({
                                        msgId: msgId,
                                    });
                                    // console.log('------new ------',new Date())
                                    await db.ref("/timings/" + refId).update({
                                        lastMailSentOn: new Date(),
                                    });
                                }
                            }));
                            
                            // console.log('-----7-----')
                            await db.ref("/timings/" + refId).update({
                                lastEmailFetchCount: repliesCount,
                            });
                        }
                }));
            }).then(async () => {
                let count = 0;
                if(refId) {
                    const snapshot = await db.ref('/count/'+ refId).get();
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        count = snapshot.val();
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                await db.ref('/count/'+ refId).set(count+messageCount);
                // console.log('messageCount',messageCount)

                const userMessageCountArr = Object.keys(userMessageCount);
                await Promise.all(userMessageCountArr.map(async userMessageCountKey => {
                    let count = 0;
                    const snapshot = await db.ref('/users/'+ userMessageCountKey).get();
                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        let snapshotObj = snapshot.val();
                        count = snapshotObj.count || 0;
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    await db.ref('/users/'+ userMessageCountKey).update({
                        count: count+(userMessageCount[userMessageCountKey] || 0),
                    });
                }))
            })
                })
            );
        });
    });
};
```

From what I have understood the error is happening in the code given below:

```
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(`attachments/${attachment.attachmentId}`);
const snapshot = await storageRef.put(buffer, { contentType: attachment.mimeType });
const downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

I am new to this and I am not able to find any solution. Also the most weird thing is that this worked fine in the local environment.

Comment: you could try updating the version of node-fetch to a more recent version that is compatible with the version of Node.js that is installed on your server.

Comment: I am not using node-fetch as a package inside my application. The node-fetch package which is throwing the error is inside the firebase package. Currently, I am using the "firebase": "8.10.0" version. I am not sure if there is a way I can change the version of node-fetch inside the firebase package. If there is any way please suggest it.

Comment: Upgrade the Firebase package to the most recent version: Start by updating the Firebase package to the most recent version that is currently available. By offering a version of Firebase that is compatible with your present version of node-fetch, this could address the problem.

Comment: Hi @ChristianPaulAndaya, just as you mentioned it was the issue with the older version of firebase. Thanks a lot for your help. Now the functionality is working as per the expectation. Thanks a bunch again :) .

Comment: Hi @Ankit Sharma, I'll post my comment as an answer so the community can benefit from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the Firebase package to the most recent version: Start by updating the Firebase package to the most recent version that is currently available. By offering a version of Firebase that is compatible with your present version of `node-fetch`, this could address the problem